# NullPointerException, relatively easy

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Sorry to bother with a nullpointerexception question but this should be relatively easy and I don´t understand what´s causing it.

Basically there is a database called "andmebaas.txt" where all the data is separated by "###" and it should separate the information and display the ones I have requested (m2ng[0].nimi and m2ng[10].nimi)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class kt_5_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("andmebaas.txt"));
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(new File("andmebaas.txt"));
        int n;
        for(n = 0; scanner1.hasNext(); n++) {scanner1.nextLine();}
        m2ngud m2ng[] = new m2ngud[n];
        for (int c = 0; scanner2.hasNext(); c++) {
            String wholeLine = scanner2.nextLine();
            String[] line = wholeLine.split("###");
            m2ng[c].nimi = line[0]; //this is line 17.
            scanner2.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(m2ng[0].nimi);
        System.out.println(m2ng[10].nimi);
    }
}


public class m2ngud {
    String nimi, kuup2ev, tootja, zanr, hinne;
}
```

the error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at kt_5_1.main(kt_5_1.java:17)

Thanks for all your answers in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by

```
    m2ngud m2ng[] = new m2ngud[n];
```

you allocated references, all of them are still referring to `null`, you need to initialize each element, like

```
    m2ng[c] = new m2ng();
    m2ng[c].nimi = line[0]; //this is line 17.
```

before accessing them

Comment: Thanks. Buut why isn´t the    m2ngud m2ng[] = new m2ngud[n];   enough? Hadn´t I allocated memory with that already? m2ng[c] is just one of the n indexes of m2ng, after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
m2ng[c].nimi = line[0];
```

Before this, first create an object of m2ng class than access nimi variable of that m2ng class.

```
m2ng[c] = new m2ng();
```